# How to show Toast only once after received error message prop from Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have working `React-Native + Redux` registration flow:

1. Fill inputs
2. Validate them in component (Formik)
3. Call action to store `registerUser(formData)`
4. Wait for `saga` to do async call to `API`
5. On `API` error call reducer `REGISTER_ERROR` what sets store variable `formError` to some message.

I have my component with mapped state to props (this error message is hooked to prop).

I am doing `componentDidUpdate()` and when the error prop from store is changed I fire `ToastAndroid.show(errorMessage)`.

But my Toast is called multiple times, because componentDidUpdate is also called multiple times (Redux updating component multiple times).

I know quick workaround by for example creating local state `visible` and when this state variable is `true` then no other Toasts are shown.

Is there any better more common way to do it? It is pretty weird in my opinion to rely on Toast's `onClose` event to set the state variable to `false`.

Comment: Instead why can't you fire the toast after the API call itself instead of doing it in that component?

Comment: @Shivaraj Isn't that anti-pattern then? (If you mean calling it inside saga)

Comment: It would be great if we can see your code

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the first answer it'd be good to see the actual code, but what you should be doing is only showing the toast message when the prop changes like this (assuming it's a boolean)

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.showToast === false && this.props.showToast === true){
    showToast();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is good way. I will just change it to check if the actual error message changed or not and depending on this, show the toast again. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Without the code, it's a bit hard to try coming up with a solution but I think I know at a high-level what you are trying to do.

If I were you, I would make the presentational component (toast UI in this context) just react to the store props/observables instead of calling the `ToastAndroid.show()` method directly in the life cycle method.

In terms of architecture pattern, I find this pattern works well with react applications. Hope this helps. https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0